# Code readability and UI design balance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have worked a lot on improving how my code runs (and it's "beauty"), but when is the time to stop fixing, and start working on the UI?

Microsoft (in my opinion) seems to go with the nice-code, while Apple goes with nice UI (although Apple's developer examples do have very nice code).

I'm bad at balancing, when is it the time to work on one or the other?

Comment: I think the only possible answer would be "At the right time" — but that won't be helpful

Comment: Well, that sort of helps.  I guess when the UI is looking terrible, switch over to designing the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user doesn't like the program, the quality of the code is irrelevant. Once the user likes the program, then code quality becomes more important. And by "like" I mean a good user experience where the program doesn't crash, fulfills the need that the user has and adhere's to the Principle of Least Surprise.

Note I say "more important" because code is not something the user sees or is interested in. Code quality and "beauty" is important to developers because it's what they see of the program and what they hand over to other developers.

I remember reading something some time ago comparing (in general terms) software developed for the windows platform and software developed for OS X. In general terms it said that windows programs tended to be developed by developers who didn't spend too much time on the UI or thinking about the user experience. Their concentration was getting every piece of functionality they could think of into the program without any thought about it making sense. Mac OS X on the other hand tended to be developed by people concentrating on the user experience first and solving their problems. So it didn't necessarily have as much functionality, but what it did have was directly associated with what the user needed and was easy to use.

So when is it time to stop and think about the UI? The fact that you have asked the question makes me think it's time to stop right now. If anything I'd suggest that even before writing any code you should have drawn out a basic UI and worked out what sort of user experience your program is going to provide If you cannot work that out, you don't want to wasting time writing code because you will never use it.

Thats not to say I think code "beauty" is irrelevant. I spend time on making sure my code is well written, easy to follow and looks "good". But that's after I've figured out the UI and because I've had a lot of experience with cleaning up other people aweful code :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Make it work, then make it elegant, then make it fast](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2007/04/15/the_two_things_about_computer_programming/).

Comment: I like this very much for its pithy insight, but it doesn't actually address the question of user interface vs engineering quality.

Comment: Think of the UI as part of making it elegant, or easy to use. Leave the speed last.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incredibly broad question, and the answer is entirely a function of what you're building, why, and for whom.

Some random bits of conventional wisdom that I agree with:

- If you're building broadly-applicable consumer software (e.g. for Mac or iOS), then the UI is a critical component of the application. Spend lots of time on it. :) Work with designers. If your software looks like crap, no one will want to use it. (Assuming nobody's going to make them: see next point.)
- If you're building internal or enterprise tools, UI polish is probably less important.
- Even if you're a one-man (or woman) operation, think of engineering as distinct from "product management". Product management is the thought process that determines what the software should do, and how it should work (and look). Engineering creates the reality, but has different tradeoffs. These are sometimes in conflict, which is hard to handle if you're one person, but try to wear different hats.
- In all cases, your code should work, for some reasonable definition of work.
- If it's ugly because it's hacked together, you're likely to run into accuracy/correctness problems sooner than if you construct it methodically. It will also be harder to maintain. The tradeoff here is almost never worth it. As you gain experience, you'll more naturally write clean code from the start, even if it's "scratch" code. You'll save time in the long run this way, and not be faced with later wholesale attempts to improve its beauty.
- If you're on a team, or working with others, clean code is even more important. Find out if there are any "local" coding conventions, and work closely with colleagues.
- As far as improving "how code runs", if you mean performance optimization, don't do any of that until you're sure you need to. Write the simpler code first, even if it's slower. It's likely that it won't be slow enough to matter.
- Special case: if you're writing a game, long-term maintainability is less important, because they tend to be "throwaway" at some level. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you, I have gained some insight into the question.